# ELK docker access via localhost

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

I have installed docker on windows, cloned the ELK stack machine, went into cloned folder, run the following command:

```
docker-compose up
```

And when I try to access `http://localhost:5601`, or `5600` port, I get `page not found` error. What's wrong? How do I access the docker?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to access it to localhost, then you have to setup your VirtualBox VM in order to **port-forward** that port from the VM into the host.

See for instance "[Using boot2docker to run Docker on a Mac or Windows](http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/boot2docker.html)" from [**Andrew Odewahn**](https://github.com/odewahn):

[image]

That way, you don't have to find out what the IP of your machine is.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, docker is running in a virtual machine, so I guess that you have to access through the IP of this. You can execute the following command to get the IP:

> $ docker-machine ip dev

Where `dev` is the name of the virtual machine. You can use the following command to get a list of the all the virtual machine where docker is running:

> $ docker-machine ls